# One war file multiple mysql data bases in Spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am developing a web application with Spring boot. This application is going to be use for diferents companies that will have their own MySQL database and their own application.properties file but all of them are going to use the same war file. I don't know how do it, If someome can tell me or guide me how I can do that with spring boot I'll be very gratefull.

Answer (score 0):

Develop your Spring boot application to load configuration based on the profile.

Different companies can use their names as an identifier to load the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your words. I will investigate about it. Regards.